# how to access a List from another class

Tags: c#

I have created a list which can store all the input values from a text file. Now I need to access this list from another class. Does the code need any changes?

```
 public static void boxdetails()
{
    String line;
    List<Box> listofboxes = new List<Box>();
    try
    {
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("c:/boxvalues.txt"))

        while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            // create new instance of container for each line in file
            Box box = new Box();
            //  List<Box> listofboxes = new List<Box>();
            string[] Parts = line.Split(' ');
            // set non-static properties of container
            box.bno = Parts[0];
            box.length = Convert.ToDouble(Parts[1]);
            box.height = Convert.ToDouble(Parts[2]);
            box.depth = Convert.ToDouble(Parts[3]);
            box.volume = Convert.ToDouble(Parts[4]);
            box.placed = Convert.ToBoolean(Parts[5]);
            // add container to list of containers

        }
        listofboxes.Add(box);
        Console.WriteLine((box.bno) + "is ADDED");
        listofboxes = listofboxes.OrderBy(x => x.volume).ToList();
    }
    //[code incomplete]
```

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1:** Declare the `List<Box>` outside your method with `public` access modifier.

```
class ClassA
{
  public  List<Box> myList = new List<Box>();
}
```

**Step 2:** access your `List<Box>` with instance variable of that class from any other classes.

```
class ClassB
{
 ClassA aRef=new ClassB();
 aRef.myList.Add(myBox);//access here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try making `listofboxes` a member property, like this:

```
public List<Box> ListOfBoxes
{
    get
    {
        return this._listOfBoxes;
    }
    set
    {
        this._listOfBoxes = value;
    }
}
private List<Box> _listOfBoxes = new List<Box>();
```

Then change your code like this:

```
while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    // create new instance of container for each line in file
    Box box = new Box();

    //  List<Box> listofboxes = new List<Box>();
    string[] Parts = line.Split(' ');

    // set non-static properties of container
    box.bno = Parts[0];
    box.length = Convert.ToDouble(Parts[1]);
    box.height = Convert.ToDouble(Parts[2]);
    box.depth = Convert.ToDouble(Parts[3]);
    box.volume = Convert.ToDouble(Parts[4]);
    box.placed = Convert.ToBoolean(Parts[5]);

    // add container to list of containers
    this.ListOfBoxes.Add(box);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare List as Static, So that you can access from any class using class name

like,

```
ClassName.listofboxes //assign to some other list or use as per ur need
```

.....

```
public static List<Box> listofboxes;
public static void boxdetails()
{ 
    listofboxes = new List<Box>();
     ...
}
```